# Como limpar AsyncTasks da memória após execução?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um APP comercial, neste preciso carregar todos os clientes do estabelecimento, então eu faço uma requisição solicitando cada cliente, pois preciso mandar o Id deste na URL da requisição, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que quando faço por exemplo, requisição de 150 clientes funciona, isto resulta em 150 `new AsyncTask().execute();`.

Em um próximo cenário preciso requisitar 700 clientes, ou seja, 700 `new AsyncTask().execute()` então preciso limpar da memória os que já foram concluídos, ja tentei `new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());` e não tive sucesso.

---

Eu tenho um `ArrayList<Integer>` que contem os ID dos clientes que eu necessito 'pegar' ,(tenho um EndPoint que me retorna os IDs de Clientes que posso 'pegar'), então a cada sincronização mando a posição 0 desse array como parâmetro, então vai o ID do cliente ao final removo a posição 0 e faço uma verificação se ainda exite cliente sem sincronizar. 

Código do `OnPostExecute()`:

```
clientesAguardandoSincronizar.remove(0);
mAsyncCliente = null;
if(clientesAguardandoSincronizar.size()>0){
     //Executa novamente o Async de Clientes para trazer um a um.
     mAsyncCliente = new AsyncCliente(context).execute();
}else{
     //Executa proxima AsyncTask.
}
```

Comment: Sinceramente, acho que o maior problema é com a sua API. Por que não ter um endpoint na API que permita obter todos os usuários de uma única vez? Dessa maneira, você faria sempre uma única requisição em um único `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @regmoraes Não sei se é este o caso, mas nem sempre o desenvolvedor tem controle sobre as APIs que ele precisa consumir.

Comment: Como está seu código? Como essas tasks são criadas? Compartilhar o código que você já fez facilita que outros entendam seu problema e te ajudem.

Comment: Sobre o primeiro comentário, a API é de outra empresa que preciso integrar nosso app com o sistema comercial deste outro cara. eu não tenho nem um controle sobre ela, inclusive solicitei tal correção e não fizeram.

Answer (score 0):

Se alguem tiver esse problema, aconteceu isso comigo porque estava usando Volley e cada requisição ele gerada uma Thread e deixava ela na memória. Usei HTTPRequest e fiz todas as requisições da mesma AsyncTask, e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Duas respostas? Porque não uma com edições? Ou são informações relacionadas à sua pergunta?

Comment: Sou novo na página, não sei bem como funciona. Ao invés de criticar, porque o senhor não veio ajudar quando precisava?

Comment: Mas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Jovem, **não estou te criticando**, estou perguntando, você leu com calma o que escrevi? Duas respostas? Porque não uma com edições? Ou são informações relacionadas à sua pergunta? Você já fez o [tour]? É altamente recomendável, para que problemas como esse não ocorram.

Comment: São informações relacionadas a minha pergunta. A primeira é pra complementar e a ultima é pra dizer oque eu fiz pra funcionar caso alguem mais precise.

Comment: Então faça o [tour], e também leia esse post para entender como funciona o site e o [sistema de auto-resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/37/66203). Da maneira que está, está errada e pode ser removida se você não corrigir.

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado e desculpa se fui grosso.